# What is better way to store and access list of views in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I've been using backbone for quite some time now, and each time I get dynamic lists of views that have their own events and behaviors, I wonder how should they be stored. I've two ways and my thoughts on them are..

1. Store views internally in another view. This requires overhead in proper filtering, but is sort-of independent from DOM + might have better memory usage
2. Just generate views, put them in DOM and trigger events of views with jquery, like `$('#someviewid').trigger('somecustomfunction');` - easier to write and access but dependencies are harder to see and I'm not certain that view/model gets deleted if I just remove DOM node

What would you recommend?

So here is expanded second example, where new views are just appended to internal html and storyViews themselves are forgotten. But If I want to access specific view from this list, I would have to use DOM attributes, like id or data and then trigger view functions with jquery accessors

```
Devclub.Views.StoriesList = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.reset, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    reset: function (modelList) {
        $(this.el).html('');
        var me = this;

        $.each(modelList.models, function (i, model) {
            me.add(model);
        });
    },

    add: function (model) {
        var contact_model = new Devclub.Models.Story(model);
        var view = new Devclub.Views.Story({
            model: contact_model
        });

        var storyView = view.render().el;

        $(this.el).append(storyView);
    }
});
```

In contrast, I could instead store same view list in an array and iterate over it if I want to call some view methods directly

Comment: Could you include some code? The question is a bit abstract and hard to grasp, what exactly you mean.

Comment: take a look at the `CollectionView` from https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette ... it's goal is an exhaustive exercise in solving the issues you're having

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep a reference of the child views. Here is an example from the [book](https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#views-1) by Addy Osmani.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    if (this.onClose) {
        this.onClose();
    }
    this.remove(); };

NewView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       this.childViews = [];
    },
    renderChildren: function(item) {
        var itemView = new NewChildView({ model: item });
        $(this.el).prepend(itemView.render());
        this.childViews.push(itemView);
    },
    onClose: function() {
      _(this.childViews).each(function(view) {
        view.close();
      });
    } });

NewChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    render: function() {
    } });
```